# Calling another entity's repository from service layer of an entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are two entities: **Invitation** and **Group**

A user can invite another user to a group. I have a controller for the invitation Rest API endpoint and a service layer that implements the business logic.

**accept** method is defined in the invitation service layer:

```
public void accept(long invitationId, String username) {
    Invitation invitation = this.loadById(invitationId);
    User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
    validateAccessToInvitation(invitation, user);
    Group group = invitation.getGroup();
    group.addMember(user);
    invitationRepository.delete(invitation);
    // groupRepository.save(group);
}
```

I'd like to know if it is a good idea to access another entity repository (here: `group repository`) some entity service layer (here: `invitation` service layer).

One option is to add `save` method to `group` service layer. But it would only call the save on the `groupRepository`, which is somehow feels like it shouldn't be a good design.

Comment: I think it's fine when service accesses multiple repositories. It's part of business logic so use them together.

Comment: what is the best practice here ?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably consider exposing an `addMemberToGroup` method in the service layer class for groups.  Then that logic is all bundled together, and if the logic for adding members to groups ever changes in any way, you can do that in a central, obvious location.

I might even go so far as saying that this method could potentially violate the single responsiblity principle.

Comment: Do you mean we shouldn't event handle `group` entity in `invitation` service layer ?

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule that says you should or should not handle it there, so it comes down to personal preference.   Personally, I would prefer to separate the logic specific to groups into its own method in order to clearly express intent.